# Cannot compile PHP 7.3 with static ldap library on Windows

Tags: php, windows, ldap

I am trying to compile PHP 7.3 with ldap enabled (`--with-ldap`). When I am calling `cscript configure.js` with the flag `--with-ldap` or `--with-ldap=static`, then the build of PHP 7.3 fails with these error message:

```
oldap32_a.lib(controls.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_control_free already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(controls.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_controls_free already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(extended.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_extended_operation already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(open.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_init already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(unbind.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_unbind_s already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(free.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_memfree already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_err2string already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(error.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_parse_result already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(getvalues.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_count_values_len already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(getvalues.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_get_values_len already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(getvalues.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_value_free_len already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(getdn.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_dn2ufn already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(getdn.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_explode_dn already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(getdn.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_get_dn already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(result.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_msgfree already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
oldap32_a.lib(result.obj) : error LNK2005: ldap_result already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
olber32_a.lib(io.obj) : error LNK2005: ber_alloc_t already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
olber32_a.lib(io.obj) : error LNK2005: ber_free already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
olber32_a.lib(io.obj) : error LNK2005: ber_init already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
olber32_a.lib(memory.obj) : error LNK2005: ber_bvfree already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
olber32_a.lib(decode.obj) : error LNK2005: ber_scanf already defined in Wldap32.Lib(WLDAP32.dll)
C:\path\to\php-7.3.19\x64\Release_TS\php7ts.dll : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x64\link.exe"' : return code '0x491'
```

But when I call `cscript configure.js` with `--with-ldap=shared` then the build ends without errors and I get an additional `php_ldap.dll` file. So the question is

1. Why I get this error?
2. How can I compile PHP 7.3 with flag `--with-ldap=static`